# Sorting in excel with additional conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have several rows of objects, each row with a specific date.
Currently, the spreadsheet is ordering the rows by date increasing, using the ROW function.
However, I need to introduce a new ordering criteria. First, all "A" objects should come first. Then all "B" objects. Inside the same group, dates should be increasing. Example below:

[image]

[image]

How can I go about this? (Worth noting this must be done through formulas but I can add columns/indicators/whatever is necessary:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, use [SORTBY](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sortby-function-cd2d7a62-1b93-435c-b561-d6a35134f28f) function as seen on the example below.

```
=SORTBY(A2:B11,A2:A11,1,B2:B11,1)
```

Adapt the formula to your table.

[image]

Comment: That would be brilliant! Unfortunately I am not using Excel 365, but 2016...

Comment: You can try Excel online, then paste as value to local Workbook.